# How solve this matricial system

Tags: matrices, functions, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I'm trying to solve this matricial system below and had no success. I'm also not understanding why Vin(s) vanish from the system.

[Matricial System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsR03.png)
[image]
The system above leads to

[Transfer Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGPru.png)
[image]

I'm very grateful if anyone help me to solve this system setp-by-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverting the [$2\times 2$ matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2_%C3%97_2_matrices) gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}sL & 1-D \\ 1-D & -\left(sC+\frac{1}{R}\right)\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\frac{1}{LCs^2+\frac{L}{R}s+(1-D)^2}
\begin{bmatrix}sC+\frac{1}{R} & 1-D \\ 1-D & -sL\end{bmatrix}
$$
so
$$
\hat{i}_L(s)
=
\frac{\left[\left(sC+\frac{1}{R}\right)V_0+(1-D)I_L\right]\hat{d}(s)+\left(sC+\frac{1}{R}\right)\hat{v}_{in}(s)}{LCs^2+\frac{L}{R}s+(1-D)^2}.
$$
Now applying a hidden constraint that $(sC+\frac{1}{R})\hat{v}_{in}(s)=\left[(1-D)I_L-\frac{1}{R}V_0\right]\hat{d}(s)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Where does this restriction come from?

Comment: @srnlord No idea. But for sure your question is missing something.

Comment: thoose equations come from https://www.slideshare.net/divyasri0008/ssmboost?from_action=save

Seeing that could you tell me where this hidden constrait come from?